# Since the accident of the last year or something

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine someone has experienced a bad accident one year ago and then has become housebound. Which one of the following sentences sounds grammatically and structurally more correct in this respect:

> 1. She’s been housebound since **the last year accident**.
> 2. She’s been housebound since **the accident last year**.
> 3. She’s been housebound since **the accident in last year**.
> 4. She’s been housebound since **the accident of the last year**.
> 5. She’s been housebound since **the last year's accident**.

For me, no one of the sounds natural. If I'm right, please let me know the natural way of saying it.

Comment: You got pretty close, but I'd suggest "She’s been housebound since **last year's accident**". Other possibilities include "since **the accident of last year**".

Answer (score 1):

- 'She’s been housebound since the last year accident.' **NO**
- 'She’s been housebound since the accident last year.' **YES**
- 'She’s been housebound since the accident in last year.' **NO**
- 'She’s been housebound since the accident of the last year.' **NO**, but perhaps 'She’s been housebound since the accident of last year.', particularly if she had an accident last year, and one the year before, but she’s been housebound only since the accident of last year and not the earlier one.
- 'She’s been housebound since the last year's accident.' **NO**, but 'She’s been housebound since last year's accident.'

Comment: I wonder what the down-voter was objecting to. #2 seems to be be the best of the OP's list.

Comment: An up-vote from me @Warren Ham. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your examples are almost correct.  The problem is that you don't need "the" if you use an adjective or some other determiner to specify which you mean.  These are some of the possibilities:

> She's been housebound since *the* accident last year.
>
> She's been housebound since *last year's* accident.
>
> She's been housebound since *her* accident last year.

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 is fine as it is, and it’s the only one that is.

Number 5 would be fine without the word “the”, and in fact would then become my overall preference.

Number 4 would also be acceptable if the second instance of “the” were deleted, but it wouldn’t be how I’d say it.

Numbers 1 and 3 are simply and irreparably wrong.